# Azure Ad b2c custom policy, iframe: Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

i have a web application (using ASP MVC), i embed an angular website, this page uses Azure Ad b2c for user authentication.

I get the error: `Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'`

This is my Signup And Signin Policty:

```
<UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <!-- get AppRoleAssignment -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="GetUserAppRoleAssignment" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GetUserAppRoleAssignment" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="CustomSignUpSignIn" />
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <JourneyFraming Enabled="true" Sources="https://.io https://testsquid.dynatex.io" />
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
....
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
```

this is my Multi tenant AD config in B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORKEXTENSIONS.xml

````
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <Domain>microsoftonline.com</Domain>
      <DisplayName>Common AAD</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AADCommon-OpenIdConnect">
          <DisplayName>Multi-Tenant Azure Ad</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ProviderName">https://login.microsoftonline.com</Item>
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
            <!-- Update the Client ID below to the Application ID -->
            <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">openid profile email</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
            <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
            <Item Key="client_id">....23-34e2ae21b7eb</Item>
            <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com</Item>
            <!-- <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,https://login.microsoftonline.com/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</Item> -->
          </Metadata>```
````

Comment: Hi @quanchinhong, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 1):

•   The below error that you are encountering while using Azure AD B2C user authentication is not because of a misconfiguration in Azure AD B2C custom policy. It is because of an **issue in the web browsers’ cookie management policies and settings configured**. Because, since **Azure AD and Azure AD B2C both rely on cookie-based session authentication mechanism, the authentication information is stored in the browser memory in the form of cookies and only allowed or authenticated information from valid sources is allowed to be shown on the page through them**.

Thus, I would suggest you to please **ensure that the browser versions are up-to date** and the setting ***`‘Block third party cookies’ is disabled`***. You will have to go to **‘Settings --> Privacy and Security --> Site settings --> Cookies and site data --> Set ‘Block third party cookies to OFF’'**

•   Doing the above should help you to resolve the issue, also ***ensure that you are disabling the ‘Flash and Ads blocker extensions’ too which are messing up with the AAD authentication***.

Hence, doing the above should help you to resolve the issue. Please refer the below links for more details on the above: -

**https://blog.atwork.at/medium.aspx?id=c14c3ae3-3aba-429d-a748-b74283dbd463&date=/post/2020/09/13**

**https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/84**